# Get Variable from String Parameter MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am having some trouble implementing a RecordResults for a specified event id. It needs to be able to do - the event entry listed at the bottom of the page should include a
hyperlink that will take the administrator to a new web form for recording results for that event. The
EventID is passed via a query string parameter, e.g. RecordResults.php?EventID=4.

At the current time I have this code to show:

Records Data into Database

```
   <?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_select_db("clubresults") or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {    
$EventDate = date('D-m-y', $EventDate);
$sql="INSERT INTO events (EventName, EventDate, Location)
VALUES
('".$_POST['EventName']."', '".$EventDate."', '".$_POST['EventLocation']."')";

$add_event = mysql_query($sql);

echo "Successfully Added 1 Event";
}
?>
```

HTML Form + Generate Table from MySQL Database -

```
<h2> Add Event To Database </h2>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Event Name: <input type="text" name="EventName" /><br>
Event Date: <input type="text" name="EventDate" /><br>
Event Location: <input type="text" name="EventLocation" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Event" />
</form>

<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM events";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Error in Query');

echo '<table width=100% border=1>';

echo '<tr><td><b>Event ID</b></td><td><b>Event Name</td><td><b>Event Date</b></td><td><b>Event Location</b></td><td><b> Record Results</b></td></tr>';

while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))

{

echo '<tr>';

echo '<td>'.$row[0].'</td>';

echo '<td>'.$row[1].'</td>';

echo '<td>'.$row[2].'</td>';

echo '<td>'.$row[3].'</td>';


echo '</tr>';

}

echo '</table>';

mysql_free_result($result);



?>
```

I have also been working on this however am not sure how to use this to make a add results hyperlink for each row in the table which passes the URL String.

```
    // Get id from URL
$id = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['EventID'] );

// If id is number
if( (int)$id== $id && (int)$id> 0 ) {

     // Get record from database
     $sql = 'SELECT * FROM Evernts WHERE EventID=' . $id;
     $result = mysql_query( $sql, $link );    
     $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

     // Show record with HTML here - Need to show it in the table!
     print_r( $row );

} else {

   echo "Record not found";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks :D

Comment: Using string concatention to generate SQL? Ever heard of SQL Injection?

Comment: This is for a college assignment - What the specification asked for.

Comment: -1 for justifying it. If this is what they teach you in college, god help use when you start developing for real...

Comment: Tell your teacher you don't want to learn outdated stuff. Does he teach you PHP4 too?

Comment: It's a basic class... If I don't follow the assignment spec ill get marked down.  Dumb College

Comment: Can you tell us what doesn't work? And what are this `$EventDate = date('D-m-y', $EventDate);` and this `if( (int)$id== $id ...)` supposed to do?

Comment: What doesnt work is that there is a table with the output of the sql database - I am trying to add a colum which fills with RecordResults for the specified Event ID in that row.  That $EventDate was a failed attempt at adding a date to an sql db

Comment: @user1371500 in your Mysql table, what is the data field that you have?, DATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer with some advice.

- Try to be consistent when you name things. You have variables that start with a capital letter such as `$EventDate`, some not like `$result` and some with underscores `$add_event`. Use [camelCase](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) to name your variables. The same goes with you table column names in your database : you have EventName, EventDate and then Location...
- Try to understand what you do. PHP is kind of permissive and won't complain with instructions like `$EventDate = date('D-m-y', $EventDate);`. You don't need to declare variable so it will evaluate $EventDate to 0 (`$EventDate = date('D-m-y', 0)`). Read the [manual](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php) if you don't know what a function do or how to use it.
- Do not use the star character in your select queries. Name explicitly all the columns you want to retrieve.
- You have to learn outdated ways of doing things in PHP and it's a shame for you teacher. So be aware of better solutions such as [PDO](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php) and [prepared](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/pdo.prepare.php) or [quoted](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/pdo.quote.php) statements.

From what I understand you want to display all the events from the database in a HTML table.
And have the possibility to add an event via a form. 
You also want to link the event to a record results page passing the event id as a parameter in the URL (you are not clear on this). index.php

```
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("clubresults") or die(mysql_error());

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {   
        $eventName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['EventName']);
        $eventLocation = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['EventLocation']);
                    // if you want to retrieve the date via the form 
                    // you have to check the format so that it corresponds to 
                    // what your date column expects (default format is Y-m-d)
        $eventDate = date('Y-m-d');

        $sql = "
            INSERT INTO events (EventName, EventDate, EventLocation)
            VALUES (
                '" . $eventName . "', 
                '" . $eventDate . "', 
                '" . $eventLocation . "'
            )";

        $addEventQueryResult = mysql_query($sql);

        if ($addEventQueryResult)
        {
            echo "Successfully added 1 event";
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "Error adding the event";
        }
    }
    ?>

    <h2>Add Event To Database</h2>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        Event Name: <input type="text" name="EventName" /><br>
        Event Date: <input type="text" name="EventDate" /><br>
        Event Location: <input type="text" name="EventLocation" /><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Event" />
    </form>

    <?php

    $query = "
        SELECT EventId, EventName, EventDate, EventLocation 
        FROM events";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Error in Query');

    echo '<table width="100%" border="1">';

    echo '
        <tr>
            <th>Event ID</th>
            <th>Event Name</th>
            <th>Event Date</th>
            <th>Event Location</th>
            <th>Record Results</th>
        </tr>';

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $addResultLink = 
                '<a href="recordResults.php?EventId=' . 
                $row['EventId'] . 
                '">Add Results</a>';

        echo '<tr>' 
                . '<td>' . $row['EventId'] . '</td>' 
                . '<td>' . $row['EventName'] . '</td>'
                . '<td>' . $row['EventDate'] . '</td>' 
                . '<td>' . $row['EventLocation'] . '</td>' 
                . '<td>' . $addResultLink . '</td>' 
           . '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';

    mysql_free_result($result);
    ?>
```

Here is the recordResults.php which retrieve an event based on the event id in the URL and display the event with the same HTML table than above. Do whatever you want next. Note: this code should be refactor so you don't write the same HTML table twice.

```
<?php

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris'); 

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "sqlflo54") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("clubresults") or die(mysql_error());

    // Get id from URL
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['EventId']);

    // If id is number
    if ($id > 0) 
    {
         // Get record from database
         $sql = "
            SELECT EventId, EventName, EventDate, EventLocation 
            FROM events 
            WHERE EventId = " . $id;
         $result = mysql_query($sql);    

         echo '<table width="100%" border="1">';

         echo '
            <tr>
                <th>Event ID</th>
                <th>Event Name</th>
                <th>Event Date</th>
                <th>Event Location</th>
            </tr>';

         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
         {
            echo '<tr>' 
                    . '<td>' . $row['EventId'] . '</td>' 
                    . '<td>' . $row['EventName'] . '</td>'
                    . '<td>' . $row['EventDate'] . '</td>' 
                    . '<td>' . $row['EventLocation'] . '</td>'  
               . '</tr>';
         }

         echo '</table>';

         mysql_free_result($result);
    } 
    else 
    {
       echo "Record not found";
    }
?>
```

I hope this will eventually help you understand what you want to do. 
Don't copy and paste this code because I changed some of the variable names to stick with the above advice.